# Select one related entity per category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

On structure like below I have to get one comment for each `origin` per article, ordered by created_at.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum origin: [ :a, :b, :c ]
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Basically if I have multiple comments for article I want to display only one comment by `origin`.

Comments are eager loaded with articles in one query (multiple articles are displayed on one page with picked comments).

Is it possible to make this work using one AR query, that will keep eager loading so app don't have to run separate select for each article on comments?

Comment: use includes to avoid multiple query i.e Article.includes(:comments) in the controller action you are using.

Comment: @DyaniyalNadar - unfortunately that's not what this question is about. If you read my question more carefully you will notice that I already use eager loading.